# Save date as the key in object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save to firebase realtime-db one object inside an array that has a key and a value.
The key is today's date, and the value is another object, named `dataObject`.
But it doesn't recognize the word 'today' as the today's date variable.

It's saving it as just a string like that:

`data: [ { "today": dataObject } ]`

That's what I've tried that didn't work:

```
 const today = new Date();

                firebase.database()
                .ref(`users/${user.uid}`)
                .set({
                  data: [{ today: dataObject }],
                });
```

I wanted that the array will be sorted by dates. That's what I've tried that did work but doesn't seem very elegant:

```
const today = new Date();

                firebase.database()
                .ref(`users/${user.uid}`)
                .set({
                  data: [{ today, dataObject }],
                });
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation):

```
const today = new Date();

firebase.database()
  .ref(`users/${user.uid}`)
  .set({
    data: [{ [today]: dataObject }],
  });
```

This should add an array like this:

```
[
 { 'Mon Sep 06 2021 15:29:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)': dataObject }
]
```